# Can I update a deeply nested immutable object without making it aware of its context?

Tags: oop, kotlin, immutability

Let's imagine I have a nested immutable object graph, along these lines (using Kotlin syntax, but hopefully it's clear):

```
data class House(val bedroom: Bedroom, val bathroom: Bathroom, val kitchen: Kitchen)
class Bedroom
class Bathroom
data class Kitchen(val oven: Oven, val kettle: Kettle)
class Oven
data class Kettle(val on: Boolean)

var house = House(Bedroom(), Bathroom(), Kitchen(Oven(), Kettle(false)))
```

Now, I want to switch the kettle on. If the objects were mutable I would just write:

```
data class Kettle(var on: Boolean) {
    fun activate() {
        this.on = true
    }
}        
house.kitchen.kettle.activate()
```

But because they are immutable I have to write:

```
data class Kettle(val on: Boolean) {
    fun activate(house: House): House {
         return house.copy(kitchen = kitchen.copy(kettle = kettle.copy(on = true)))
    }
}
house = house.kitchen.kettle.activate(house)
```

(Actually, it's slightly more complicated, but this pseudo-code will do).

I don't like this, not because it's long, per se, but because the Kettle now needs to know not just about its own internal state, but about the full context it exists in.

How can I rewrite this so that each object can be responsible for providing its own mutation logic, without having to be aware of the full object graph? Or am I just trying to marry object-oriented and functional concepts in an impossible way?

Comment: I think the line requested from you code (on the naive approach) is:
`return house.copy(kitchen = house.kitchen.copy(kettle = house.kitchen.kettle.copy(on = true)))`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant about it being more complicated in reality - the example is slightly simplified

Comment: I think you could do it by adding a `turnKettleOn` (or something along this) to `House` and then make it create a new representation of itself with just replacing the `Kettle`. Though that might restrain your code as every `Kitchen` will have to have a `Kettle`

Answer (score 1):

This is where functional lenses show their power. For example, using [poetix/klenses](https://github.com/poetix/klenses),

```
val kettleLens = +House::kitchen + Kitchen::kettle

var house = House(...)
house = kettleLens(house) { copy(on = true) }
```

Comment: Hi I looked into functional lenses, but I can't see how they help me here. A lens lets me concisely describe that the path from House to Kettle in a reusable way, which I like. But in order to update the Kettle I still have to know about the full structure. There's no way to localise the concern to the Kettle's own methods. Unless I'm missing something about lenses?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach I thought of (this is the question asker, by the way) was like this:

```
data class Kettle(val on: Boolean) {
    fun activate() {
        return Transform(this, Kettle(on = true))
    }    
}

class Transform<T>(val what: T, val replacement: T) {
    fun <U> apply(x: U): U {
        if (x is T && x == what) {
            return replacement as U
        } else {
            return x
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that a transform is a function you can apply to every object in the graph and it will only modify the `what` you told it to modify.

So you use it like this:

```
val transform = house.kitchen.kettle.activate()
house = house.transformEverything(transform)
```

Where every class has an implementation like this:

```
data class House(val bedroom: Bedroom, val bathroom: Bathroom, val kitchen: Kitchen) {
    fun transformEverything(transform: Transform): House {
        return transform(this).copy(
                bedroom = bedroom.transformEverything(transform),
                bathroom = bathroom.transformEverything(transform),
                kitchen = kitchen.transformEverything(transform)
        )
    }
}
```

Which recursively gives the `transform` a chance to modify every object it wants to, and it will only apply it to one.

This approach is bad because:

1. Tons of boiler-plate giving everything its own dumb version of the `transformEverything` method
2. It seems weird (and inefficient) to have to call an function on every object in the graph just to change one.

But it does achieve my goal of the Kettle not needing to know anything about its context, and it's pretty straightforward to write the `activate` function. Thoughts?